# Facebook LIKE button, not collecting correct information

Tags: facebook, meta, facebook-likebox

When integrating 3 social network buttons (TWEET, +1 and Facebook) Facebook is the only one not picking up the correct data.

When reading the documentation, there appears to be no reason why it should not. It will not pick up the picture of the page in question and instead picks up a user icon and it will not pick up any content.

It should pick up the core content automatically but failing that uses META tags. These too are not helping it.

This appears just after the opening BODY tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=250606741665703";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

This appears in the HEAD

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Belgian Empire" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.robin-knight.com/the-belgian-empire-201112/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.robin-knight.com/wp-content/uploads/Untitled-11-212x160.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Quite Cheesed Off" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="597180443" />
```

And this is the button

You can see an example here:: http://www.robin-knight.com/the-belgian-empire-201112/

Comment: Try using the debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug it'll show any errors with the markup and/or if there's a redirect you've forgotten (Facebook takes the meta tags from the last step of any redirect chain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to find bugs associated with the open graph.
Type the following url into the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.robin-knight.com%2Fthe-belgian-empire-201112) (without the slash at the end):
http://www.robin-knight.com/the-belgian-empire-201112
Now you will see that the debugger says: 
*Object at URL* 'http://www.robin-knight.com/the-belgian-empire-201112/' *of type* 'article' *is invalid because it specifies multiple* 'og:url' *values:* http://www.robin-knight.com/the-belgian-empire-201112/, http://www.robin-knight.com/the-belgian-empire-201112/.
When you look into your source code you will find two times the og:url meta tag. That's your problem.